# Read one column from one row from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a quick and dirty way to get the value of one column from one row? Right now I use something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $row['value'];
```

It seems there must be able to consolidate the second and third lines.

These three lines seem like a lot just to get the value from one column from one row. I tried this:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1'");
  return mysql_fetch_array($result)['value'];

But that doesn't work. I am just trying to find out if there is a simpler,  more to the point, way of getting one value like this.

Comment: When you say "consolidate the 2nd and third rows" are you trying to do some sort of aggregation like 'sum' or 'average'?

Comment: i don't know why the downvotes (the question *is* legitimate), but you're confusing readers with rows vs lines.  you may want to edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1'");
return mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this hacker)

```
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1'"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat ) function to make them into one field.

Answer (score 0):

Do u want this?

```
$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $output[] = $row['value'];
}
return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
return $row[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. HOwever, this is essentially the same. You've just replaced the name with an index.

Comment: I don't really see how you can query faster than doing a query and return? Should also be using prepared statements these days so expect even more code if your looking for a safe site.

Answer (score 0):

What you should look for is an encapsulation mecanism. For example you could create a classe User that would correspond to a rows of SQL table "user". Then you could get his id just with a single line:

```
$user->getID();
```

You could also create a class that would aggregate all the user and then use something like this:

```
$collection->getUserID("3435563");
```

But really there isn't a simpler way to do it in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to return only one value use the limit keyword

```
/* Limits Results to 1 */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE row_id='1' LIMIT 1;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
echo $row['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple function to contain your lookup-code, which you can call for your database lookups in a single statement.